# What is the name of this paradox?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, paradoxes

What is the name of the mathematical paradox which is arises from the following?

If we imagine a point on a two-dimensional coordinate system (line graph), which moves from the positive part of the graph to the negative (if I can say like that), we expect that at one moment this point will cross the coordinates axis (for example axis of ordinates).

When the point is approaching the aforementioned axis, the distance to it constantly reduces. The distance may be a 1 unit, then 0.1 unit, then 0.01, then 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001... It seems that the point will never cross the axis, because the distance between it and axis may reduce infinitely, thus it may be infinitely small.

However, anyone can take a pencil, draw coordinates and then draw a line from one part of the graph to the opposite, crossing the axis without any difficulty. Isn't it a mathematical paradox?

I am not a mathematician myself, so I beg your pardon if you find my explanation of a problem a bit awkward.

Comment: Of course it's not really a paradox if you know just a bit elementary calculus. If your particle is moving at speed 1 unit per second. If it starts at 1, it will take time 0.9 to get to 0.1, then 0.09 to get from 0.1 to 0.01 and so on. So it will take time 0.9 * (1 + 1/10 + 1/100 + ...) = 0.9 * 10/9 = 1 to get from 1 to 0, which is what you'd expect. Moral: the sum of infinitely many terms can be finite, if they drop down fast enough.

Comment: Sincerely this still looks paradoxically to me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is Zeno's paradox of motion. You can read more about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes

Comment: Seems like this is `Dichotomy paradox`. Thanks!

Comment: Or should we say _decatomy paradox_? ;-)